# How can I make TextToSpeech to speak a text with max volume and restore original volume after speak end?

Tags: android

I save the current volume both `STREAM_RING` and  `STREAM_MUSIC` before `sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)`, I hope the `TextToSpeech` can speak a text with max volume,
but in fact I find the `TextToSpeech` speak the text with current volume, it seems that `sTts.get().speak` is asynchronous.

How can I make `TextToSpeech` to speak a text with max volume and restore original volume after speak end? Thanks!

```
public class SpeechTxt {
private static SoftReference<TextToSpeech> sTts;

public static void SpeakOut(final Context context, final String s) {
    final Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    if (sTts == null) {
        sTts = new SoftReference<TextToSpeech>(new TextToSpeech(appContext,
                new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            speak(appContext, s);
                        } else {                                
                        }
                    }
                }));
    } else {
        speak(appContext, s);
    }
}

private static void speak(Context context, String s) {
    if (sTts != null) {
        switch (sTts.get().setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())) {
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE: {

            sTts.get().setPitch((float) 0.6);
            sTts.get().setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);

            int currentRing=PublicParFun.GetCurrentVol(context, AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            int currentPlay=PublicParFun.GetCurrentVol(context, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            PublicParFun.SetRingVol(context, 0);
            PublicParFun.SetPlayVol(context,1000000);

                    sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

            PublicParFun.SetRingVol(context, currentRing);
            PublicParFun.SetPlayVol(context,currentPlay);

            break;
        }
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA: {

            break;
        }
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED: // not much to do here
        }
    }
}


public static int GetCurrentVol(Context myContext,int streamType){
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int current = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume( streamType);   
    return current;
}   

public static void SetRingVol(Context myContext,int vol){       
    SetVol(myContext,AudioManager.STREAM_RING, vol);
}


public static void SetPlayVol(Context myContext,int vol){
    SetVol(myContext,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, vol);
}

private static void SetVol(Context myContext,int streamType,int vol){
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int max = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType);
    if (vol>max){
        vol=max;
    }
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(streamType,vol, 0);
}
```

}

**Edit**

1. Is the following code right? I fixed my original code by your thinking.
2. I can't understand why the code need to add HashMap, I think `sTts.get().setOnUtteranceProgressListener` and `sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener` don't need HashMap, right?

   HashMap ttsParameters = new HashMap();
   ttsParameters.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");

package bll;
public class SpeechTxt {
    private static SoftReference sTts;

```
public static void SpeakOut(final Context context, final String s) {
    final Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    if (sTts == null) {
        sTts = new SoftReference<TextToSpeech>(new TextToSpeech(appContext,
                new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            speak(appContext, s);
                        } else {                                
                        }
                    }
                }));
    } else {
        speak(appContext, s);
    }
}

 private static void speak(Context context, String s) {
        if (sTts != null) {
            switch (sTts.get().setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())) {
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE: {

                sTts.get().setPitch((float) 0.6);
                sTts.get().setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);

                final int currentRing=PublicParFun.GetCurrentVol(context, AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                final int currentPlay=PublicParFun.GetCurrentVol(context, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                PublicParFun.SetRingVol(context, 0);
                PublicParFun.SetPlayVol(context,1000000);

                final Context myContext=context;

                HashMap<String, String> ttsParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ttsParameters.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=15){
                    sTts.get().setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDone(String utteranceId)
                        {
                            PublicParFun.SetRingVol(myContext, currentRing);
                             PublicParFun.SetPlayVol(myContext,currentPlay);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String utteranceId)
                        {
                            //also, set the volume back
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStart(String utteranceId)
                        {
                           // set the volume to max
                        }
                    });

                }else{                  
                  sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                         PublicParFun.SetRingVol(myContext, currentRing);
                         PublicParFun.SetPlayVol(myContext,currentPlay);
                    }
                   });
                }
                sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParameters);
                break;
            }
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA: {
                break;
            }
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED: // not much to do here
            }
        }
    }
```

}

**Edit Again**

I test many times, when sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParameters) speak a short string, the  sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() is invoked correctly.

but if  sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParameters) speak a long string (about 15 seconds), it seems that  sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() is not be invoked. Why?

```
        sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                 PublicParFun.SetRingVol(myContext, currentRing);
                 PublicParFun.SetPlayVol(myContext,currentPlay);
            }
           });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem could be, that You set the currentRingVolume directly safter You started the TTS. The code will not wait until the speech has ended. For setting the volume back to the current volume, do it after speech has finished with an UtteranceProgressListener (or onUtteranceCompletetListener < API 15. this depends on which API You are developing):

```
   //first set the HashMap to Your tts
   HashMap<String, String> ttsParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
   ttsParameters.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");
   tts.speak("Say Hello",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ttsParameters );
```

Set onUtteranceProgressListener:

```
   int result = tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId)
            {
                //here set the volume back
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId)
            {
                //also, set the volume back
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId)
            {
               // set the volume to max
            }
        });
```

### EDIT

and for API < 15:

```
   tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {

        //set volume back
    }
   });
```

To find out what version is installed:

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=8){

     }
```

Comment: Thanks! but Call requires API level 15 (current min is 8): android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech#setOnUtteranceProgressListener, is there other way?

Comment: That´s what I said, under API15 You need onUtterenceCompleted listener. It´s the same way You have to implement it, there is just one method inside the completed listener: onUtteranceCompleted() <--there You have to set the volume back

Comment: ...sorry, I see, that something has killed the half of my answer, maybe that "something" was myself. I just edit it...

Comment: ok, strange behaviour here in the forum, the part of my answer in the brace is not showed, whay that?

Comment: thats what I wrote in braces: (or onUtteranceCompletetListener <API 15. this depends on which API You are developing):

Comment: I mean I hope the my code can work under API 8 or higher, but your code can only work under API 15 or higher.

Comment: yes :) ....That is what I wrote..please see my comments and the Answer where I set the words in braces. For showing You the way for < 15, I will make an example

Comment: Thanks! but why need I first set the HashMap to TTS in the code you written, I think I can delete both HashMap<String, String> ttsParameters = new HashMap<String, String>() and 
ttsParameters.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId"), right?

Comment: To  Opiatefuchs, would you please have a look at my edited content? Thanks!

Comment: No, the HashMap is required for both listeners to let the Engine know to use a listener. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks! In ttsParameters.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId"), can I replace stringId with any string?

Comment: And more, is there public void onError(String utteranceId) event when API < 15 ?

Comment: Yes You can use any String, that´s not important. onError is only in the UtteranceProgressListener, that´s why the completeListener is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks!

I test many times, when sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParameters) speak a short string, the  sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() is invoked correctly.
but if  sTts.get().speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParameters) speak a long string (about 15 seconds), it seems that  sTts.get().setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() is not be invoked.

Comment: Usually QUEUE_ADD is only for added strings, that means, for example, if You let the engine speak like speak("HELLO",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,params);, it is the first time. If You want to let the engine speak again with a second speak(), right after the first, then You have to use speak("HELLO",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,params); . So if the engine speaks the first time, use QUEUE_FLUSH. And, I don´t know if it has a effect, I think You shoud use new params with another string id if You want to add a text.